# Find multiple values from one spreadsheet among mutiple .txt files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to find 60 unique values amongst 17 .txt files. This is usually a simple "find" and copy, when I receive the values one or two at a time, which is obviously not going to work for me with this large a list.

The spreadsheet has around 60 account numbers. I need to locate each account number in one of 17 .txt files, so I can copy that account row into another .txt file for editing/completion. The .txt files are in an ftp archive, so I have to be careful not to alter the .txt files at all, although I could copy them to excel, if necessary.

I know there are lookup functions, but I'm not very familiar with them yet and not sure exactly what I need. I'd appreciate some help with this one! Thanks, L

Answer (score 0):

I have knocked up a script you may find helpful.

Create a folder called **accounts** and save the script there with .vbs extension.

Create a folder in the accounts folder called **input**. copy all the accounts files to be searched to the input folder, they should all be .txt files or they will be ignored.

Create a file called **account_numbers.txt** and list each account number there on a separate line. The script should open each file, read a line and check it against every account number. The results of the search are stored in **accounts_found.txt**. Supplied without warranty, use at your own risk. Hope it helps.

```
' find all occurrances of an account number in a number of files
' place all account txt files into input folder
' accounts_found.txt is created if it is missing
' by 'Robert' 2017 - hereby placed into the Public Domain

' set some Constants here
Const ForRead      = 1
Const ForWrite     = 2
Const ForAppend    = 8
Const OverWrite    = True
Const NoOverWrite  = False

Dim acct_num_list(100) ' max records for the array, num_accounts variable counts them anyway

inputFolderName    = "input\"               ' the folder where the txt files are
outputFileName     = "accounts_found.txt"   ' the output file for matched records
accountsFileName   = "account_numbers.txt"  ' the file which contains account numbers to search for

' = = = Start of Code = = =

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(outputFileName, ForWrite, OverWrite)

Set objInputFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(inputFolderName)
Set sFileCollection = objInputFolder.Files

Set accounts_file = objFSO.OpenTextFile(accountsFileName, ForRead)

num_accounts = 0
DO While Not accounts_file.AtEndOfStream
    acct_num_list(num_accounts) = accounts_file.ReadLine
    num_accounts = num_accounts + 1
Loop

accounts_file.Close

For Each objFile in sFileCollection
    If UCASE(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "TXT" then
        Set sourceFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inputFolderName & objFile.Name, ForRead)
        Do While Not sourceFile.AtEndOfStream
            curr_line = sourceFile.ReadLine
            For counter = 0 to num_accounts
                if instr(1, curr_line, acct_num_list(counter),1) >= 1 then
                    outFile.WriteLine curr_line
            End If
            Next    
       Loop 
    End If    
Next
' = = = End Of File = = =
```